# How to set vcpkg static for every platform?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, vcpkg

Lets say I'm using `vcpkg` and  I want to install a package as `static` no matter the platform
I know I can do it with a triple like wxwidgets:x86-windows-static
however, how can I say "make it static for every platform"?

Answer (score 3):

You want to read https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md.

The triplet variable you are looking for is `VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE`. Setting it to `static` in a triplet makes every library/port - which supports it - build as a static library.

Comment: I have tried using `set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)` but it doesn't change the triplet. Any ideas?

Comment: What did work is `if(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET MATCHES "windows")
    set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}-static")
ENDIF()`. Still looking for a good setting to link properly with MSVC though.

Comment: You need to learn that your `CMakeLists.txt` and a vcpkg triplet are two different things. Changing `VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE` in your cmake project does nothing,it only has affect in a triplet. 

Your triplet setting should always be a preset setting or a cache variable so users are free to overwrite it and use something different. For example I have a triplet which is called `x64-windows-llvm`. Applying your code would thus break with an non-existant triplet.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Lesson learned, haha. I've made a small `include()`d cmake file which overrides the triplet on windows to `...static-md`. Maybe a cleaner mechanism will be available in the future. This is what I did, in case anyone wants to see. https://gist.github.com/NickStrupat/630ba7bc1d4b3072c5279bff0adb4ba2

Comment: Scratch that, it doesn't work.

Comment: > Scratch that, it doesn't work.

a) always have `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)` at the top of your toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`    
b) make sure it has been set before `project()`    
c) changing triplets in an already configured tree is not possible. You have to do a clean configure for it to work   
d) rather then forcing the triplet consider passing it via the cmd line or [cmake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html)

Comment: Thanks for your expertise! Is there a decent way to have `vcpkg` use whatever compilation settings are being used by the consuming project? Ideally I wouldn't need to maintain two sets of compilation flags.

Comment: Ah, it seems cmake presets is likely the way to manage this.

Comment: > use whatever compilation settings are being used by the consuming project

You will need a toolchain and a custom vcpkg triplet to use that toolchain. In the triplet you simply set `VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to the path to your toolchain and you do the same on the command line for your project.