# How to add vcpkg variable in visual studio with cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, vcpkg

**What I need:**

I want to use cmake tool to add `x86-windows-static` in **Triplet option** and `Debug` in **Vcpkg Configuration**.

Look the screenshots below,

[image: vs screenshot 1]

↓

[image: vs screenshot 2]

**What I have tried:**

I read some docs to changed these vars, but failed.

- [Triplet files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/triplets)
- [How to set vcpkg static for every platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807164/how-to-set-vcpkg-static-for-every-platform)

My part code in CMakeLists,

```
...

if(WIN32 OR CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM Win32)
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET "host=x86" CACHE STRING "Platform Toolset" FORCE)
#set vcpkg
set(VCPKG_ROOT_DIR "C:/Users/xxx/vcpkg" CACHE PATH "set vcpkg path")
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${VCPKG_ROOT_DIR}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
message(VCPKG_ROOT = "${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}")
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x86)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE static)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
set(VCPKG_CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Empty)
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x86-windows-static")
endif()

project(my_project)

...
```

**Output:**

```
$ cmake -B build
VCPKG_ROOT=C:/Users/xxx/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/my_project/build
```

Reopen .sln project, no happended in the **Triplet option** and **Vcpkg Configuration**,they are still empty.

BTW, I can use `VS_GLOBAL_VcpkgEnabled` to change **Use Vcpkg**

`set_target_properties(my_project PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_VcpkgEnabled true)`

[image: vs screenshot 3]

But I cannot change the other vcpkg options.

**My question:**

Can I modify the relevant variable values in CMakeLists to change the vcpkg options in VS project?

If not, is there any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks as much about Visual Studio as vcpkg: add that tag?

Comment: @TooTone visual-studio tag added.